# Windows BATCH file gives me weird spaces in my variable

Tags: windows, batch

I was trying to make a simple batch file that scans a variable X for any spaces and then creates a modified variable Xmodified that does not include any spaces. Here is the code I used:

```
@echo off
set Xmodified=[
set "X=I am good"

:space1
IF "%X:~0,1%" == " " ( goto space2 ) Else ( set Xmodified=%Xmodified%%X:~0,1% )
goto space2

:space2
IF "%X:~1,1%" == " " ( goto space3 ) Else ( set Xmodified=%Xmodified%%X:~1,1% )
goto space3

:space3
IF "%X:~2,1%" == " " ( goto space4 ) Else ( set Xmodified=%Xmodified%%X:~2,1% )
goto space4

:space4
IF "%X:~3,1%" == " " ( goto space5 ) Else ( set Xmodified=%Xmodified%%X:~3,1% )
goto space5

:space5
IF "%X:~4,1%" == " " ( goto space6 ) Else ( set Xmodified=%Xmodified%%X:~4,1% )
goto space6

:space6
IF "%X:~5,1%" == " " ( goto space7 ) Else ( set Xmodified=%Xmodified%%X:~5,1% )
goto space7

:space7
IF "%X:~6,1%" == " " ( goto space8 ) Else ( set Xmodified=%Xmodified%%X:~6,1% )
goto space8

:space8
IF "%X:~7,1%" == " " ( goto space9 ) Else ( set Xmodified=%Xmodified%%X:~7,1% )
goto space9

:space9
IF "%X:~8,1%" == " " ( goto Finishing ) Else ( set Xmodified=%Xmodified%%X:~8,1% )
goto Finishing

:Finishing
set Xmodified=%Xmodified:~1%
goto Display

:Display
cls
echo Your Processed Result:%Xmodified%
pause >nul
```

Output:

```
Your Processed Result: I a m g o o d
```

Can someone tell me why the output includes spaces after every letter? From where did these spaces come?

How do I make the output like this?

```
Your Processed Result:Iamgood
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: See [EnableDelayedExpansion - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: I tried it but it did not work.

Comment: Use [CMD Variable edit replace - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) to replace all the spaces at once.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve here is remove spaces, not replace them. In the final application, the original variable will not be known. The purpose of the application in this issue is to check character by character and only add non-space characters to the Xmofidified new variable to produce a spaceless variable.

Comment: Yes, but you can replace the space with nothing! See my answer.

Comment: Just put `set Xmodified=%Xmodified: =%` just above the cls in the :Display routine

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How do I remove spaces from a variable?

If you are going to use `for` or `if` (which have expressions using brackets) then you would need to use Delayed Expansion.

However there is a much easier solution that removes the spaces all at once:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "X=I am good"
set _result=%X: =%
echo %_result%
endlocal
```

---

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [EnableDelayedExpansion - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [Variable edit replace - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)